# What are the default attributes of a mutex?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

What are the default mutex attributes?
I am specifically looking for value of default robust attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

From [man pthread_mutexattr_getrobust](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.html) we can see that default robust value is:

> **PTHREAD_MUTEX_STALLED_NP**
>
> No special actions are taken if the owner of the mutex is terminated while holding the mutex lock. This can lead to deadlocks if no other thread can unlock the mutex.
> This is the **default** value.

which means that mutex is **not robust** by default.

### Long story (how it's done in pthread code)

Looking into [glibc sources, "nptl/" directory](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=nptl;h=afe0179ccfb60221f9f8d0bf0d56c649d08023e2;hb=HEAD), we can see next stuff.

Default attributes will be used when calling:

```
pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *mutex,
                   const pthread_mutexattr_t *mutexattr)
```

with `mutexattr = NULL`.

In that case `&default_attr` structure will be used:

```
int __pthread_mutex_init (mutex, mutexattr)
{
    imutexattr = (const struct pthread_mutexattr *)mutexattr ? : 
                 &default_attr;
```

Which is:

```
static const struct pthread_mutexattr default_attr =
{
   /* Default is a normal mutex, not shared between processes. */
   .mutexkind = PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL
};
```

The same is done for `pthread_mutexattr_init()`:

```
((struct pthread_mutexattr *) attr)->mutexkind = PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL;
```

Where `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL` is:

```
PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL = PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP,
```

and `PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP` is 0 (because it's first element in enum).

So by default all mutex attributes are 0 (because they are basicaly just bits in `.mutexkind` field of `pthread_mutexattr` struct).

Robust is bit #30 in `.mutexkind` field:

```
#define PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_FLAG_ROBUST       0x40000000
```

And robustness is calculated like this:

```
  *robustness = ((iattr->mutexkind & PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_FLAG_ROBUST) != 0
         ? PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST_NP : PTHREAD_MUTEX_STALLED_NP);
```

So **default robustness** is `PTHREAD_MUTEX_STALLED_NP` (because `mutexkind` is 0 by default).